# Como atualizar um componente e voltar para seu estado inicial?

Tags: javascript, web-service, react-native

**A autenticação:**

1. Tem uma tela de login produzida com linguagem nativa (react-native), que ao fazer login num servidor remoto através de um webservice, acessado por um componente importado dentro do meu app, onde ele me retorna um hash do tipo jwt, e algumas informações do usuário, quando logado corretamente.
2. Em seguida ele faz uma segunda autenticação, que é na nossa base de dados, onde ele pega os dados completos deste usuário, e cria uma autenticação de navegação e acesso por cookie, que é carregado dentro de uma webview.
3. Esta webview está definida dentro do app nativo, e é renderizada ao verificar se existe um jwt.
4. Através da navegação no webview, eu tenho o controle de urls que são enviados para a camada nativa (react-native), uma destas urls e a rota de saída (logout), então quando bato nesta página o sistema faz o logout, porém a aplicação fica com uma tela em branco e perde a tela inicial de login nativo, e este é o **problema**:

   A tela do nativo(react-native) não atualiza, e não consigo recomeçar o processo de login depois disso.

Eu estou utilizando Hooks na página, ou seja, não tem mais uma classe instanciada onde eu posso ficar reinstanciando o render com o `componentDidMount()`.

A [documentação](https://pt-br.reactjs.org/docs/hooks-state.html) não tem nada sobre como fazer para trabalhar com hooks e webview.

Tem esse github que também não explica nada de [como usar com hooks](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-webview).

Eu até tentei fazer como se fosse um return do App, mas não funcionou, veja o código:

```
import React, { useState, Fragment, Component } from 'react'
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
import { WebView, onNavigationStateChange } from 'react-native-webview'
// import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';  
// import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { Login } from 'combo-mobile'
import { NativeModules, Platform, Alert, Button, TextInput, View, StyleSheet, Text, Modal, Keyboard, Linking } from 'react-native'
import CookieManager from 'react-native-cookies'
import { 
  DOMAIN_APP,
  TEST_PARAMS_LOGIN,
  APPLICATION_ENV
} from './src/config/env'
import {version as appVersion} from './app.json'

//O aplicativo que é exportado...

const App = () => {
  
  const [jwt, setJWT] = useState(null)
  const [urlWebview, setURL] = useState(`${DOMAIN_APP}/path/index`)
  
  const json_encode_platform = btoa(JSON.stringify({
    tk_os:Platform.OS, 
    tk_os_version:Platform.Version,
    tk_version_app:appVersion
  }));

  const jsLib = `window.postMessage("{script:'${DOMAIN_APP}/js/add-script-${Platform.OS}-platform.js',platform:'${json_encode_platform}'}");`

  const _onNavigationStateChange = (webViewState) => {
    console.log('nav -> '+Date.now())
    console.log(webViewState)
        if (typeof webViewState.url !== 'undefined') {
          _loadingStatus = false
          setURL(webViewState.url)
  
          if(urlWebview !==  `${DOMAIN_APP}/path/index`) {
             console.log('navigation-change')
            if(urlWebview.indexOf('external_id') !== -1) {
                Linking.openURL(urlWebview);
            }

            if (urlWebview.indexOf('/logout') !== -1) {
                console.log('fez logout...')
                CookieManager.clearAll();
                console.log('limpei login')
                 /* 
                  AQUI DEVERIA VOLTAR TUDO NOVAMENTE PARA O ORIGINAL
                  ::: SÓ QUE ESTÁ DEIXANDO A TELA EM BRANCO ::: 
                */
                 setJWT(false)
                 setURL(`${DOMAIN_APP}/path/index`)

                /*
                   AQUI É A TENTATIVA DE FAZER ELE 
                   RENDERIZAR, SÓ QUE NÃO FUNCIONOU
                */
                 return goWebcombo()
               
            }
          }
       }
   }


  const _createCookie = (name, value, call) => {
      CookieManager.setFromResponse(`${DOMAIN_APP}/, ${name}=${value};path=/;expires=2030-05-30T12:30:00.00-05:00;secure`)
          .then((res) => {
            console.log('setFromResponse.set =>', res);
            CookieManager.get(`'${DOMAIN_APP}/'`)
            .then((resGet) => {
                console.log(resGet[name]);
                if (resGet[name] != undefined ){
                    console.log('COOKIE SETADO????? =>', resGet);
                    call();
                }
              });
          });
  }
  
  const _cookiesTypeLogin = () => {
      if (DOMAIN_APP) {
          CookieManager.clearAll() 
          _createCookie('tk_os', Platform.OS, (res) => {
               _createCookie('type_login','app', (res) => {
              })
          })
      }
  }

  let _loadingStatus = true;

 const defaultUrlAuthenticate = `${DOMAIN_APP}/path/api/oauth/auth?tk_os=${Platform.OS}&tk_os_version=${Platform.Version}&tk_version_app=${appVersion}&jwt_combo=${jwt}&url=${encodeURIComponent(
  //   `${DOMAIN_APP}/path/index`
  // )}`

 
 //O comboJWT é o componente externo que atribui o jwt

 //render() {
  const webCombo = (
    <Fragment>
      <Login product="productName" onLoginCombo={({ comboJWT }) => {
         setJWT(comboJWT)  
          if(jwt) {
            //seta cookie da origem
             _cookiesTypeLogin()
          }
      }} />
      {
       //aqui verifica se o jwt foi criado e carrega a webview
        jwt && (
          <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <WebView
              style={{ flex: 1 }}
              onNavigationStateChange={_onNavigationStateChange}
              onError={_onNavigationStateChange}
              source={{ uri: defaultUrlAuthenticate }}
              javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
              mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
              allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
              javaScriptEnabled={true}
              domStorageEnabled={true}
              injectedJavaScript={jsLib}
              startInLoadingState={_loadingStatus}
              thirdPartyCookiesEnabled={true}
              useWebKit={true}
              sharedCookiesEnabled={true}
              onMessage={e => {
                 //print the data coming from the angular app to the console, data.newUrl should have the new url
                console.log("data from angular app:",e)
                console.log("teste", e.nativeEvent)
                e.nativeEvent.loading = false;
                _loadingStatus = false;
                 const dataMessage = e.nativeEvent.data;
                     if (dataMessage.open_url != undefined) { 
                         Linking.openURL(dataMessage.open_url);
                     }
                }
              }
              />
          </SafeAreaView>
        )
      }
    </Fragment>
  )
  const goWebcombo = () => {
     return webCombo;
  }
  //criei como um método só para tentar renderizar (só que não fez nada)
  return goWebcombo();
  //  }
}

export default App
```

Eu tentei usar o useEffect, mas veja o erro que deu:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: O problema é que tu não consegue usar um hook equivalente ao `componentDidMount()`?

Comment: Eu acho que é: `useEffect` ou `useCallback`, mas não sei como aplicar o uso deles aqui.

Comment: Pensei se não seria `useEffect(App, [])`...

Comment: Basicamente, o equivalente ao `componentDidMount` é o `useEffect(função, [])`, caso você queira o "substituto" dele.

Comment: Como você faria utilizando o `componentDidMount`? Daria certo? Você já tentou converter esse componente funcional para um _class-based_?

Comment: O [Antigo era assim](https://gist.github.com/ivanferrer/af497cb85f42f2bfceccf75de6d6cdc8)

Comment: Ou seja, basicamente um modal que era fechado por cima..., só que mudaram tudo... e eu estou tendo que refazer isso, usando hook.

Comment: Se executar o que tá dentro do `componentDidMount` resolve o teu problema? Se sim, basta executar o que tá dentro do corpo com o use effect da forma que eu falei ali...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema foi solucionado colocando / removendo do AsyncStorage, e incluindo useEffect:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, Fragment, Component } from 'react'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-community/async-storage'

  const [loadingToken, setLoadingToken] = useState(true)

  const SafeArea = ( <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
    <WebView
      style={{ flex: 1 }}
      onNavigationStateChange={_onNavigationStateChange}
      onError={_onNavigationStateChange}
      source={{ uri: gutenURL }}
      javaScriptEnabledAndroid={true}
      mixedContentMode={'compatibility'}
      allowsInlineMediaPlayback={true}
  ...
 )

   useEffect(() => {
      AsyncStorage.getItem('comboJWT').then((data) => {
        if (data && !jwt) {
          setJWT(data)
        }
        setLoadingToken(false)
      })
    })

    const _onNavigationStateChange = (webViewState) => {
        if (typeof webViewState.url !== 'undefined') {
            _loadingStatus = false
            setURL(webViewState.url)

            if (urlWebview !== `${DOMAIN_APP}/path/index`) {

                if (IsValid(urlWebview,'/logout')) {
                    AsyncStorage.removeItem('comboJWT')
                    setJWT(false)
                    setStatus(0)
                }
            }
        }
    }

const webCombo = (
      <Fragment>
        {
          !jwt && !loadingToken && comboJWT && (
            <Login product="productName" onLoginCombo={({ comboJWT }) => {
                setJWT(comboJWT)  
                  AsyncStorage.setItem('comboJWT', comboJWT)
                if(jwt) {
                    setStatus(statusLogin + 1)
                }
            }} />
          )
        }
        {
          jwt && safeArea
        }
      </Fragment>
    )
    const goWebcombo = () => {
        return webCombo;
    }
    return goWebcombo();
```